# ServiceBusTrigger Azure function throwing TaskCanceledException while waiting API call response

Tags: azure, function

We have a ServiceBusTrigger Azure Function. During the execution of an event, it will make an API call to different service. However, before the API call returns with result, if it takes longer time, the Azure Function would throw an exception with message like the following:

Exception while executing function: FunctionName One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.) A task was canceled.

From the multiple occurrences, this happened after the event is triggered by 100 seconds.

My question is: Is this due to timeout? If yes, why it's timing out/cancelling the task only after 100 seconds? Shouldn't the Azure Function default timeout be 5-minute?

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After more tests, it was determined the timeout/cancellation was due to the API call as a default timeout of 100 seconds. After changing to a longer timeout, the issue was resolved.